# Why Linear Layot XML Error on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

Can someone tell me what wrong with my code??[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFDhi.png)

Comment: What code? --- [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I see 2 `<LinearLayout>` start tags, but only 1 `</LinearLayout>` end tag. The indentation shows the discrepancy very clearly too.

Comment: @gilang based on the image you provided, it seems like you forgot to end 2nd LinearLayout. you can end the linearlayout with </LinearLayout> at the second last line of your code.

Answer (score 1):

CLOSE THE SECOND LINEAR LAYOUT
[image]